# Plotting software used in old scientific papers

Tags: vector-graphics

Does anyone know what software was used in many old scientific papers (please see attached example). I love the clean look of the graph and the typeface.
Thanks.
[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLABG.png)

Comment: Could it be an old version of gnuplot? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. That particular Figure is from the 1990s, but I've seen the style in older papers too. I may ask some of my more senior colleagues what they remember using back in the old days!

Comment: Not sure if you'd have better results on [hsm.se], but might be worth a quick search there. [retrocomputing.se] is probably more of a long shot